# Apache in front of JBoss 6 -> Some proxy errors

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd, jboss, tomcat6

Here under my Apache configuration:

```
<IfDefine TOMCAT>
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
       <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
          ProxyTimeout      300
          SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
          SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
          ProxyPass        /unproxied/ !
          ProxyPass        /error/ !
          ProxyPass        /   http://127.0.0.1:8080/ retry=0 ttl=600
          ProxyPassReverse /   http://127.0.0.1:8080/
       </IfModule>
    </IfModule> </IfDefine>
```

Here my JBoss connector configuration:

> ```
>     <Connector
>         address              = "${jboss.bind.address}"
>         port                 = "8080"
>         maxThreads           = "200"
>         acceptCount          = "100"
>         scheme               = "https"
>         secure               = "true"
>         proxyName            = "mydomain.net"
>         proxyPort            = "443"
>         xpoweredBy           = "true"
>         connectionTimeout    = "600000"
>         compression          = "on"
>         enableLookups        = "false"
>         maxKeepAliveRequests = "-1"
>         maxHttpHeaderSize    = "50000"
>         />
> ```

In my Apache error.log:

```
[Tue Jul 16 09:54:54 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Tue Jul 16 09:57:35 2013] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
```

[EDIT] These errors appear around 1000 times per day but my web application seems to work as expected.

What could be the problem ?

Thanks,

Bob !

Answer (score 0):

Is SELinux enabled and enforcing?

If so, you'll need to `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1` to allow Apache to make connections to JBoss.

Comment: I've forgotten an important thing. My web application works as expected, but some times, every 10 minutes perhaps, I've these errors in my log file.

Comment: @BobSauvage Ah, ok.  Do you know if the errors coincide with failures of user requests?  (they'll get a 503 response, look for those in the logs)  What kind of load is the application under?

Comment: Indeed, several proxy errors coincide with a 503 response...

The load is difficult to measure but it is quite high. Just to have an idea: 

netstat -aln | grep 8080 | wc -l => 810

Comment: @BobSauvage Might be bumping into the JBoss thread limit, then, causing rejected connection attempts -- check what the `maxThreads` setting is for your port 8080 connector in the `server.xml` file?

Comment: maxThreads = "200"

How can I check the number of threads ?

Comment: No problem, I've checked with JMX: --mbean="jboss.web:name=http-127.0.0.1-8080,type=ThreadPool --attribute="currentThreadCount" => 20. You already helped me a lot, I have to discuss about 503 errors with the development team tomorrow. These errors concerns a new view ;)

Comment: @BobSauvage Gotcha.  Let me know what you find out!

Comment: The problem is still present but appears less frequent, about 10 times a day. :(

Comment: In the kern.log, I can see that for each 503 error (proxy error), I have an invalid SYN tcp packet: 

 kernel: invalid:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14985 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50708 DPT=8080 WINDOW=32792 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Comment: @BobSauvage Interesting.  Can you try capturing one of those apparently invalid packets via `tcpdump`?

Comment: Hahaha, I am glad to see that we are thinking along the same lines ! I scheduled this test on monday :) ! Will keep you updated, maybe I will try tomorrow.

Comment: tcpdump didn't help me a lot... I found the TCP packet: 

`15:27:11.863103 IP 127.0.0.1.53716 > 127.0.0.1.8080: Flags [S], seq 1102362290, win 32792, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 969253337 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<.k@.@.%O..........$.A............'....@....
9...........`

But the followed packet was another request. So the JBoss server didn't seem to ack the SYN packet... What could be the reason ?

Comment: @BobSauvage You'll want to get it into a pcap file with `-s 0 -w filename.pcap` - feeding it to wireshark will do some more thorough analysis, and should tell us if the packet's invalid or if the kernel's wrong about saying it's invalid.

Comment: The pcap file is opened in wireshark, how can I check if the packet is really invalid ? Many thanks for your help in this topic...

Comment: since I've added the rule in order to accept invalid packets, I've another error in the Apache log: "(110)Connection timed out: proxy:". With this rule, in wireshark, I can see that JBoss is accepting the connection with a SYN ACK but the connection is immediately closed by Apache with a RST packet. Why is Apache sending an invalid or RST packet ? How can I check that ?

Comment: @BobSauvage Wait, you needed an `iptables` rule for accepting the invalid packet, on the loopback interface?  That's.. strange.  Since it's loopback and all, would you be able to add a rule accepting all traffic?  I kinda suspect that `RST` is coming from `iptables`, not Apache.

Comment: Yes, firewall rules have been build by another administrator. In the INPUT chain, I've a rule that logs and REJECTS all INVALID packets: `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTBL invalid:"` and then logs and REJECTS not SYN but new: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTBL new-not-syn:"`, `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` (cause of the RST). You absolutely right, RST is coming from iptables. I noticed this there are few hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips. The problem was related to these iptables rules. I accept now all packets from 127.0.0.1 to and from 8080 and I don't see this kind of errors anymore. I've sent an email to the iptables mailing-list. Do you think I should add a rule in order to accept ALL packets from and to 127.0.0.1 in the begining ?